# How to get property file in a Configuration class implementing BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Configuration class that is implementing BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor , In this I have to take some properties from the Property file use them in the postProcessBeanDefinitonRegistry. When I try to autowire the ApplicationContext I noticed that the ApplicationContext object is coming as null and so does all the other injected objects. On looking into the explanation for "BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor" I came to know that it executes early.

Question is :: How do I read my property values in the class that is implementing BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have modified the post accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the above issue. I understood that for my code logic "**BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor**" is not suitable. For my scenario I had to implement the "**ApplicationContextAware**" interface.